# Magento Sitemap

Tags: magento

I have about 3500 products in magento cart, when I generate sitemap from admin, it generate only 2268 url, is this correct amount, as I have categories, layered navigation, but layered navigation Urls are not being displayed.

Any Idea

Comment: What about noindex, canonical, redirect etc. URLs? None of those should be included in your sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly all products have a unique URL and should be displayed in your XML file.

- All products activated?
- All products sorted in categories?
- Are really 3500 products available on your shop? Or is it only your complete Stock?

You can check and go to **Admin->Catalog->URL Rewrite Management** there you can see all your URLs. Perhaps you can check which products are not included in your Sitemap and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is most likely correct if you have either:
 1. configurable products who's simple associated products are not set to display individually.
 2. out of stock products and products that are out of stock set to not display.